# Does a noun's plural ending determine if it is WEAK noun?

Tags: grammatical-case, noun, grammatical-number, weak-declension

If the plural form of a noun ends in "-(e)n", does this *necessarily* mean that it is a weak noun (and thus will need "n-deklination")?

In other words, is it sufficient to look at a noun's plural form to determine if the noun is a weak noun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. That is because only masculine nouns may be weak, and there's plenty of feminine nouns that have an -(e)n ending in nominative plural.

Also, to determine the correct weak pattern, you need to know the genitive singular form. Compare:

- der Witz, des Witzes, Witze — strong
- der Junge, des Jungen, Jungen — regular weak
- der Name, des Namens, Namen — -ns genitive weak

So for masculine nouns, you have to remember nominative singular and plural, and genitive singular. For feminine and neuter nouns, only the former two.

Oh, and *das Herz* is completely irregular. It's the only irregular noun German has.